# Big hit 2 chainstay design

Tags: mountain-bike, frames

Hi guys this may have been brought up before but any advice would be great. I've got a 2007 model specialized big hit 2 fsr. The frame seems an odd design to me where the main pivot is behind the bottom bracket but the chainstay has a sharp drop immediately behind the bottom bracket. The frame has mounts for ISCG old chain devices but the design of the chainstay severely limits the type of chain device that can be used effectively.

My question is would damage the structural integrity of the frame etc if I was to remove the chainstay and refit it upside down? I think this may make for more clearance around the ISCG mounts.

Any advice on this would be great

Comment: This does not sounds like a good idea, if it is even possible to reconnect upside down, i would think if this design were better they would have built them that way in the first place. I'm sure the way that the suspension pivots would be effected as well

Comment: Not entirely. The frame is basically a set of triangles joined by the main pivot behind the bottom bracket and the rear shock linkages. The seatstay and chainstay are 2 separate units. The seatstay has all the fitting for derailleur brake wheel etc and the chainstay bolts to the seatstay then to the main pivot.

Comment: I'm thinking of flipping the chainstay upside down then refitting it to the rear triangle.

Comment: yeah i had to look at a closer image of one, i see what your saying but i would imagine that it would throw something off, geometry or the way that it pivots. i cant imagine getting any real benefit out of it without equal problems arising

Comment: A couple of photos might help the question be more accessible.  If you flip the stay, can you unflip it later?  Or is there some level of cutting required ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to upload photos on here at all I've tried a few times. There would be no cutting involved at all. The chainstay is bolted on the main pivot and connected with a single bolt each side forward of the rear axle. I'd say about 10min job to unbolt it flip it over and bolt it back together. It would eliminate the sharp drop directly behind the bottom bracket...but the chainstay would no longer be horizontal with the chain it would slant upwarda

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this is the frame in question, maybe different color, but the reason this won't generally work applies to most designs.

[image: Bighit FSR]

The chainstay link is connecting its dots in 3 dimensions, not just 2. In other words, it's not flat; the distance from the pivot to the frame centerline is a different, larger number in back then in front. So even if the way the hardware interfaces wasn't an issue, which for most frames it would be, you can't just flip it upside down because it won't connect the dots right anymore.

Say you were asking a similar question but more from a fabrication standpoint; i.e. you were thinking about making a new chainstay link that did connect the dots but took a little different path for clearance reasons or whatever. Generally that's fine if you make it strong enough, design it right, etc. There are various full squish frames with very different looking pieces left and right.